# Can sunder be used on non-objects?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack

According to the sunder special attack entry in the *Player's Handbook*, page 158, "You can use a melee attack with a slashing or bludgeoning weapon to strike a weapon or shield... (Attacking held objects...is covered below)."

However, according to the "Behind the Curtain: Hydras" sidebar under the hydra's entry on page 155 of the *Monster Manual*, "Characters without the Improved Sunder feat will find it difficult and dangerous to attack by lopping off the monster's heads..."

The rules don't specifically mention this as a possibility, but spells like *regenerate* and abilities like regeneration suggest limb loss may occur.

Is the sidebar implying that sunder attempts can be made against a hydra's heads, and, extrapolating from that, can sunder attempts be made against other creatures' tentacles, arms, legs, or heads, possibly resulting in instant death attacks?

Comment: AD&D had the Vorpal Sword that chopped off the head. In 3.5 this kind of "instant death attacks" is simulated by the "death by massive damage" rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hydras are a special case:

> A hydra can be killed either by severing all its heads or by slaying its body. To sever a head, an opponent must make a successful sunder attempt with a slashing weapon.

<sup>(*Monster Manual* pg. 155)</sup>

Without this clause, you could not do this. That is because sunder is defined as

> You can use a melee attack with a slashing or bludgeoning weapon to strike a weapon or shield that your opponent is holding.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook* pg. 158)</sup>

So unless there is a special exception, like there is for hydras,<sup>1</sup> you can only use sunder on weapons or shields held by an opponent. You cannot extrapolate outward from the hydra’s special case to other creatures; that is not how the rules work.

1. <sup>And, as far as I know, no other creatures. But of course, with the size of 3.5 it’s entirely possible there are more, so I could not swear to that.</sup>

Comment: Giant Squid is another example of a creature with a special exception allowing you to sunder its limbs.

Comment: Likewise the Giant Octopus and Kraken.