# What happens when you sunder a natural weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver, natural-weapon

Under the sunder rules you can destroy things by dealing them damage by using the combat maneuver rules? If you are having a hard time with attack roles, could you switch to CMB checks. Granted this only works on natural weapons.

Comment: Possibly related [Are there any rules for sundering natural weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87426/are-there-any-rules-for-sundering-natural-weapons)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks) are typically immune to [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Sunder)

The combat maneuver [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Sunder) says, in part, that a creature "can attempt to sunder an item held or worn by [an] opponent." [Natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks)—"attacks made without a weapon"—are typically neither held nor worn, rendering them immune to the combat maneuver sunder.

Were a creature to grab a foe's somehow-severed limb and start beating his foes with that severed limb only to have one of the creature's foes make a sunder attempt against the severed limb, *then* the GM would determine the severed limb's [hardness and hit points](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects#TOC-Hardness). However, until then, targeting natural attacks with the combat maneuver sunder isn't typically a thing unless specific rules state otherwise (q.v. the [hydra](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/hydra)).

Comment: Beating my enemies senseless with preserved severed hydra heads is now totally my next character build.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: I have a DM who gave me a feat called "use your head". "your" is to be understood as "the one you have in your hand".

Comment: @AnneAunyme The I'm-not-making-it-up *3.5e* general feat Heads Up (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 100) allows a creature to employ a no-more-than-1-day-old severed head's gaze attack thrice so the creature can totally Harry Hamlin the  kraken at the end of [*Clash of the Titans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clash_of_the_Titans_(1981_film)) (1981). (And, TDW, the feat's benefit explains, "Retrieving the head from a slain creature is a full-round action that provokes an attack of opportunity.")